# Get Conduit Standard Sizes in Revit Mep 2014

Tags: revit-api

How do I get Conduit Standards with sizes using the Revit MEP 2014 API?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to access/change this information. A wish list item has been raised to address this.
[See forum post on Autodesk](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Revit-API/Add-and-Get-Conduit-Standard-and-their-Sizes-in-Revit-2014/m-p/4544693/highlight/true#M4829)